# Canceling mobx autorun function on componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have the following autorun function in my componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.autoUpdate = autorun(() => {
            this.setState({
                rows: generateRows(this.props.data)
            })
        })
    }
```

The problem is that another component changes this.props.data when the component is not mount - and therefor I get the .setState warning on an unmounted component.

So I would like to remove the autorun once the component unmounts.

I tried doing:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.autoUpdate = null
}
```

But the autorun function still triggers. Is there a way to cancel the mobx autorun once the component is not mounted any more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`autorun` returns a disposer function that you need to call in order to cancel it.

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.autoUpdateDisposer = autorun(() => {
      this.setState({
        rows: generateRows(this.props.data)
      });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.autoUpdateDisposer();
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```